# react native --preserve-symlinks support?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

### The problem

I am developing an npm package for react native, and would like to `yarn link` (or `npm link`) it into my test app repo for testing. The package has peer dependencies on `react` and `react-native`. When I attempt to run the test project, I get an error message:

```
Unable to resolve module `react` from `Users/username/Documents/module`
```

And because `react` is a **peer dependency** it is installed in the test project, not the module. So this makes sense. But doing research, it seems the `--preserve-symlinks` would solve my problem by search for dependencies of `module` the test project's `node_modules` folder, instead of in `module`'s. But from what I can tell, there is no way to run `react-native start` with the `--preserve-symlinks` flag.

I tried the following two variants:

```
$ react-native start --preserve-symlinks
$ react-native --preserve-symlinks start
```

But both were met with the message:

```
`error: unknown option `--preserve-symlinks'`
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to enable `--preserve-symlinks` globally somehow or otherwise in this instance?

### Code

`my-module`'s `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "*",
    "react": "*"
  }
}
```

`test-project`'s `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "my-module": "*"
  }
}
```

To link the two I ran:

```
$ cd my-module
$ yarn link
$ cd ../test-project
$ yarn link my-module
```

### More Investigation

I have found that adding `react` to the `devDependencies` of `my-module` solve the error, though with the obvious caveat that multiple copies of react will be loaded. Strangely, `react-native` does not cause a problem, and seems to load fine as a `peerDependency`. This solution will not work, however, because certain features of React that I am using require that there be only one copy.

Comment: Stop-gap solution: I ended up writing a script in `package.json` that copies the `lib` folder to the react native app's `node_modules` folder. I setup a file-watcher that automatically runs this script whenever `lib` changes. Since there's no linking, this resolves the error, but it doesn't feel right.